# How to select value number of ENUM types in MySql?

Tags: mysql, enums

I need to select a row from table below, but the problem is the value in `$row['city']` is the textual represent of the value, and i need its number(Toronto = 2). (Same as when we INSERT INTO, and we use value number instead of text)

Requests Table Structure:

```
req_id INT
uname  VARCHAR(30)
city   ENUM('New York', 'Toronto', 'Las Vegas')
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to force your `city` into a numeric context, from the [fine manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html):

> If you retrieve an `ENUM` value in a numeric context, the column value's index is returned. For example, you can retrieve numeric values from an `ENUM` column like this:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT enum_col+0 FROM tbl_name;
> ```

So you want this sort of thing:

```
select req_id, city+0
from your_table
where city = 'Toronto'
```

BTW, you can insert an `enum` using either the string or integer representation.

Comment: +0 is a nice and easy tweak to shortcut CAST(... AS UNSIGNED) as it seems. Cool and thanks!

Comment: This gives a float representation eg: 1.0 casting sounds to be a better option!

Comment: @SteveMoretz Are you sure that's MySQL giving you a float and not your interface misinterpreting something? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vd3AtaKXZAqRB9Aaj5DJ9Y/0 looks like it is returning integers and everything suggests that enums are 16bit unsigned integers internally.

Comment: Then sounds like something's wrong on my end! Sorry.

Comment: @SteveMoretz A type cast should also work and if it works better with whatever interface you're using then I'd go with a type cast and move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: That's exactly what I did! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `CAST` function. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html) doesn't mention this specific use case, but it works as expected. I prefer it because it looks elegant and clear:

```
SELECT CAST(city AS UNSIGNED) FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Note though that in MySQL server 5.5.38 (Ubuntu 12.04) this solution doesn't work if the table is a view which maps an ENUM column directly. The enum_col+0 solution works also in 5.5.38 instead.